# How to merge row of a dataframe under conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I need your help to merge some rows of a dataframe under conditions

Please find below an example of my dataframe:

```
ID=c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A1", "A3", "A6", "A1", "A2", "A5", "A6")
G1=c(1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0)
G2=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
G3=c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
G4=c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
G5=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
G6=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0)
G7=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0)
G8=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,0,0)
G9=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,3,2)

 data
   ID G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 G7 G8 G9
1  A1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  A2  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  A3  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  A4  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
5  A5  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
6  A6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
7  A1  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
8  A3  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0
9  A6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
10 A1  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  3  0
11 A2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  0
12 A5  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  3
13 A6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2
```

I would like to merge the raw with the same ID in the dataframe under this conditions:

if a same ID have more than one value in a same column, I want to keep the lowest value in the merged row (this is the case for A1 and A6).

Below is the desire output of my dataframe following these rules

```
   ID G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 G7 G8 G9
1 A1  1  0  0  0  0  0  3  3  0
2 A2  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  3  0
3 A3  0  0  1  0  0  2  0  0  0
4 A4  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
5 A5  0  0  0  0  1  3  0  0  3
6 A6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps we can use `aggregate` like this

```
> aggregate(. ~ ID, df, function(x) ifelse(sum(x > 0), min(x[x > 0]), 0))
  ID G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 G7 G8 G9
1 A1  1  0  0  0  0  0  3  3  0
2 A2  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  3  0
3 A3  0  0  1  0  0  2  0  0  0
4 A4  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
5 A5  0  0  0  0  1  3  0  0  3
6 A6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `min_` (from `hablar`)

```
library(hablar)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), ~ replace_na(min_(.[. > 0]), 0)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 10
  ID       G1    G2    G3    G4    G5    G6    G7    G8    G9
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A1        1     0     0     0     0     0     3     3     0
2 A2        0     1     0     0     0     0     0     3     0
3 A3        0     0     1     0     0     2     0     0     0
4 A4        0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
5 A5        0     0     0     0     1     3     0     0     3
6 A6        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```